# SonarQube Code Smell: Rename "setUp" method overridden from TestCase class

Tags: python, unit-testing, sonarqube

We've started to use SonarQube to analyze our python code and its reporting the following minor "code smell":

[image]

That is a method that I'm overriding from the `TestCase` class so I can't rename it to `set_up()` to match python naming conventions. How can I ignore the rule or adjust the Python rule to ignore this. We use Nosetests all over the place and most of them contain a setUp() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule should be fixed so that it does not raise issues in such cases. I created a [ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPY-250) to track this issue.

As a workaround, you may disable the rule for some given files. See the documentation for [ignoring issues on Multiple Criteria](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues), and apply it for python:S100 and for the pattern "**/test/*" (for example).

Comment: Thanks, I think that is what I will need to do until the issues is resolved. I've voted for it and will start watching it for resolution. I'll look into adding the regex for that rule to ignore test files.